# Is it ensured that 2 sequential std::chrono::steady_clock::now() will not be equal?

Tags: c++, c++14, std, clock, c++-chrono

I want time points picked in the same running thread to never be equal. That's because I use time points to differentiate between different calculation results.

Pseudocode:

```
StampedResult fn() {
  auto result = Calculations();
  auto time_stamp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  return {time_stamp, result);
}
```

Now, if `Calculations()` was always complex, that would be auto-solved. But sometimes, `Calculations()` may return immediately.

So, I thought I should check if 2 sequential calls to `steady_clock::now()` can return the same value, like this:

https://onlinegdb.com/BkiDAZRe8

On `onlinegdb.com` and on my laptop `Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz` I never get the same value returned. But could some other super-high frequency processor actually return the same values given `steady_clock`'s nanosecond accuracy?

Comment: Why not use a counter to generate unique calculation IDs instead?

Comment: I'm not sure that `steady_clock` is required to use nanosecond for its durations. And even if it does, I doubt it will actually have single nanosecond resolution.

Comment: Because time is required to differentiate between different running threads. If I see that time points are not always unique, maybe I will combine time points AND counters simultaneously

Comment: I don't understand why two threads can't happen to finish at exactly the same by chance. Where timestamp seems like a mediocre way of identifying results, it seems actively bad in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: I have not explained well. I want to differentiate between calculations in the same thread the way I described ^ ^. Calculations happen across, say, 3 threads. Then, another (4th) thread picks up these calculations and sorts them in order based on their time stamps. But each of the 1st 3 threads must provide uniquely-stamped results.
Hope that makes sense

Comment: Then, an a section protected by a mutex, generate UIDs that are sortable. This will do the job. It can be costly nevertheless...

Comment: @BillKotsias That seems clear, thanks. From what I understand, you want to collect the results of multiple threads and sort them chronologically. If that's the case, I would still recommend a counter. A shared `std::atomic<unsigned int>` that each worker uses to generate the next result seems like it would be much easier and safer to use. I'm not sure how it compares to reading a clock in terms of performance, couldn't guess if it's faster or slower. Edit : It would make sorting easier. Each result would already know it's final sorted index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it ensured that 2 sequential std::chrono::steady_clock::now() will not be equal?

It is not guaranteed by the standard. Quote from latest draft:

> [time.clock.steady]
>
> Objects of class steady_­clock represent clocks for which values of time_­point never decrease as physical time advances and for which values of time_­point advance at a steady rate relative to real time.
> That is, the clock may not be adjusted.

Staying the same satisfies "never decrease" requirement.

Clocks have limited granularity and if the granularity is less than frequency of calls to `now`, then it is feasible in theory that the value remains same between two calls. Complexity of the call is a practical limitation for the same value occurring again, but that is incidental.

---

If you wish to avoid duplicate value, then you can feasibly protect against the possibility by storing the last time stamp. If the new one is equal or less than the old, then nudge the new one up by one unit of measurement. The "less" part becomes possibility in case there are three equal values and second one was therefore nudged beyond the third.

Comment: Sure, I am aware that the standard doesn't guarantee it. I was hoping that current hardware limitations will at least enforce it for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @BillKotsias I don't know if there is any "enforcement". It may be that your observation is incidental.

Comment: Imagine a steady clock that is much, much slower than your CPU in ticks.  Your "nudge" could result in time stamps that are diverged to an arbitrary degree away from the current time.  This seems like a problem to me.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont If it is important to follow the steady clock closely, then it may be a problem. In that case it may be better to use a separate counter and use the timestamp and counter as a pair.

Comment: @eerorika Arbitrary, as in "decades ahead", is possible under that scheme :)  I'm just raising a caution flag of reusing a time stamp as something that isn't a time stamp.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Well, it's still a "time stamp". It's just not the time of the steady clock. The time of steady clock is also arbitrary in relation to the real wall clock.

Answer (score 5):

`steady_clock` is required to not go backwards, and it is required to progress forwards at regular intervals. That's it. It isn't even required to have nanosecond accuracy (or for the clock's actual accuracy to match the precision of its time points).

For what you're doing, making your own internal counter that goes up every time you do a calculation is a better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

No. There's no guarantee that two calls will not return the same value.

If you manage to query the clock multiple times within its resolution, you will get the same result multiple times.
How likely this is to happen depends on the clock you query, but it is *always* a possibility.

In short; you *cannot* use a timestamp as a unique identifier. You *probably* could use "timestamp + thread_id" if thread IDs are not re-used. Maybe better to sort on timestamp first, then secondly on a monotonic incrementing id assigned to each thread upon its creation. That would guarantee uniqueness and establish a fixed sort order.